# Composition API | Vue route params not being watched

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have pretty much the same example from the docs of [watch](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watch-source-types) and [vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup) for composition API. But `console.log` is never getting triggered even though the `route.params.gameId` is correctly displayed in template

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
const store = useStore()
const route = useRoute()

watch(
      () => route.params.gameId,
      async newId => {
        console.log("watch"+newId)
      }
    )
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{route.params.gameId}}
    </div>
</template>
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried making watch function non async but it didn't change anything and later on I will need it for api fetching so it should be async.

Comment: the syntax looks fine, but the watch only activates when the gameId param changes.  what are you doing to change that param value?

Comment: I tried navigating back and forth using `router.push({
name: 'game',
params: { gameId }
})`
and changing param inside url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `immediate: true` option to your watch :

```js
watch(
      () => route.params.gameId,
      async newId => {
        console.log("watch"+newId)
      },
      { 
          immediate: true

      }
    )
```

Because the watch doesn't run at the first rendering while the params is changes only one time at the page load, So the watch misses that change.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Can you just explain why?

Comment: You're welcome, please check my edited answer

Comment: Do you have any idea why is it not included in vue router docs example? Theirs example is pretty much same use case as mine.

Comment: the example is showing typical watcher behavior -- responding only to CHANGES for whatever is being watched.  activating for initial values is not the typical use case for a watcher.

Comment: @VojinPurić It's completely unreaslistic to expect the docs for *any* software to cover absolutely every use case.

Comment: You missed my point @Dexygen and @yoduh (probably looking at the example from vue docs instead of vue router docs). They are watching `route.params.id` and fetching user when it changes. I am watching `route.params.gameId`  and fetching game when it changes. I am saying that that IS the same use case as in example, but there is no mention of `immediate` flag on the whole page and also no mention of it on vue docs page

Comment: @VojinPurić The example from the docs is impractical for this reason but it's quite specific, "fetch the user information when params change". It doesn't assert that it's fetched for initial route navigation. It's not the goal of router docs to explain how to work with framework api. And this was just a snippet how to access route info, not a real-world example. Most times you may want to go with navigation guards to fetch route data because it blocks navigation